# Benefit in entering Halls of The Dead?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there any particular benefit in entering and clearing (and looting) the Halls Of The Dead present in cities? Or is it just like clearing an ancient nord ruin? Also, what special items/loot (if any) is present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Not really** - it tends to be minor scaled loot.  Occasionally a quest will take you them and each Hall contains a shrine to Arkay (increase health blessing).

There are some notable items within two of the Halls of The Dead:

**Whiterun**

> Block Skill Book
>   
> Stone of Barenziah

**Markarth**

> Restoration Skill Book

Comment: Thanks. So otherwise it's just like clearing a ruin?

Comment: Yeah, mechanically it's no different

Comment: isn't there a quest that starts in one of the halls of dead?

Comment: @z- one starts *outside* one the halls of the dead as I recall - Windhelm?

Comment: @Rory you are right, but it does lead to you going inside one.

Answer (score 4):

There's no real benefit; however I found it very useful in [J'zargo's Experiment](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:J%27zargo%27s_Experiment) quest where I needed to find three undead fast without having to end up on a wild goose chase for some Draugr!